# WPF Datagrid - subscribe to cell load event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am looking to modify the layout of a datagrid cell, in the code-behind, after the cell loads.

I know I can subscribe to the *DataGrid.Load* or the *DataGrid.LoadingRow* events, but I am hoping there is a way to subscribe to a specific individual cell's load event so that the implementation is cleaner. In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell_events(v=vs.110).aspx), it appears the cell class has the event (inherited from FrameworkElement) yet I cannot find a way to subscribe to the event cleanly.

I am using a DataGridTemplateColumn, I figured it would've been easy to do it in the XAML (CellTemplate).

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ATTENDEES" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=attendees}" x:Name="AttendeesItemsControl"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DataGridColumn.CellStyle` together with an `EventSetter` to achieve that:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="CellLoaded" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And in code-behind:

```
private void CellLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = (DataGridCell)sender;
    ...
}
```

Comment: what about the "Initialized" event ? , i did the same : <EventSetter Event="Initialized" Handler="CellLoaded" /> , it marks "Initialized" ,the event Initialized is not a routed element

Comment: @KhalilLazhar Well, as the error message states, `Initialized` is not a `RoutedEvent` and as such cannot be used with `EventSetter`. I'm not sure there's a simple way to subscribe to that event on `DataGridCell`. I don't think it is a good idea anyway, because this event fires only once, whereas `DataGridCell` can serve as a container for various cell values since it might be reused when virtualization is enabled.

Comment: Yes , that's what i want, an event which will fire just once , any ideas about the subscritpion ? thanks

Comment: After a quick glimpse at [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) I don't think there is a simple way to achieve that. However, as a workaround, you could register a `Loaded` handler which would de-register itself (by unsubscribing inside that handler) - that way it will be only called once. Other than that, I won't be of much help.